# managed DLLs Debug mixed with Release

Tags: c#, .net

There is a lot discussions regarding mixing Release and Debug unmanaged DLLs, not much regarding managed ones.
Besides the potential performance hit induced by the extra instrumentations, I am not what else can go wrong ?

I am no .NET expert, but I believe this mix up does not belong in the good practices.

Comment: Do you use 3rd Party Assemblies you don't control? In most cases you will have a mix of differently optimized assemblies anyways. You won't use "debug" builds of that 3rd Party stuff when you are debugging your own code right?

Comment: @Ralf I believe the application I have in mind does, my context is legacy applications left to "untrained engineers" without proper supervision. They built things by pieces without using a proper Solution to harmonized the build system. Hence the mess.

Comment: So you already know the answer.  It's been a disorganized mess, but it happily keeps on motoring anyway.  This is not a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is any significant issue mixing debug and release dlls in .net. I have at least never encountered any. This would also be awfully hard to avoid, since you most likely only have access release builds of third party dlls.

Debug dlls will turn of some optimizations. But all managed dlls will still be compiled by the same jitter. So there is no risk for any disagreement about memory layout or other issues that can affect unmanaged dlls.

You could still shoot yourself in the foot by using `#if debug` to intentionally make your debug and release versions different in some way. But that would be a problem with your design, not .Net.

If you are worried about legacy applications I would be more concerned about .Net versions. Officially you cannot load a library of a different major version. But several major versions have supported loading libraries targeting older versions, but usually with some limitations that may cause runtime crashes.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the mix up of .NET versions is at higher risk